# Show that in a Normed linear Space $X,\overline {B(x,r)}=B[x,r]$

Tags: metric-spaces

Show that in a Normed linear Space $X,\overline {B(x,r)}=B[x,r]$

where $\overline {B(x,r)}$ is closure of the set $\{y\in X:||y-x||<r\}$ and $B[x,r]=\{y\in X:||y-x||\leq r\}$

$\overline {B(x,r)}\subseteq B[x,r]$ follows easily but how to do the converse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any point $y\in B[x,r]$, let $y_n=x+(1-\frac{1}{n})(y-x)$. Then $\{y_n\}$ is a sequence in $B(x,r)$ converging to $y$. Therefore $y$ must be in $\overline{B(x,r)}$ by definition of the closure.

Comment: good answer man!